# composer provide / require not finding implementation

Tags: php, composer-php

Trying to use composer's [provide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#provide) feature, I added a `provide` section to my implementation repository [ffa-php-mock](https://packagist.org/packages/shadiakiki1986/ffa-php-mock), in which I say it provides [shadiakiki1986/ffa-php-implementation](https://packagist.org/providers/shadiakiki1986/ffa-php-implementation). In my repository consuming this implementation, [ffa-php-cli](https://github.com/shadiakiki1986/ffa-php-cli), I replaced the composer require [entry](https://github.com/shadiakiki1986/ffa-php-cli/blob/master/composer.json#L9) requiring `ffa-php-mock` with an [entry](https://github.com/shadiakiki1986/ffa-php-cli/blob/using_composer_provide/composer.json#L9) requiring `ffa-php-implementation`. If I try to run a `composer update`, I get the following

```
> composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package shadiakiki1986/ffa-php-implementation could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Can you give me any hints as to how to debug what the problem is?

## Edit: simplified example

I tried the `provide` feature in a dummy project on something that already exists. [jackalope/jackalope](https://github.com/jackalope/jackalope/blob/master/composer.json#L26) provides `phpcr/phpcr-implementation`, which in its turn is already required by [DoctrinePHPCRBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrinePHPCRBundle/blob/master/composer.json#L24).

If I start a new empty project with `composer init` and specify that my project depends on `phpcr/phpcr-implementation`, I get the same error as above. I also tried putting `phpcr/phpcr-implementation` directly in the composer.json file and running a `composer update`, but to no avail.

```
> cat composer.json 
{

    "require": {
       "phpcr/phpcr-implementation": "2.1.0"
      }
}
```

I would think that this is perhaps a bug in composer, but it seems from [this issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2811) that it is already in use.

```
> composer --version
Composer version 1.3.0 2016-12-24 00:47:03
```

The closest composer github issue I can find is [#2811](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2811), but that one says that the reporting isn't clear, not that `provide` doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up learning that the specific package with the implementation should still be included in the composer.json file. For packages using the library, that's ok as they get added to the `require` section. For the library that is directly requiring the implementation, that should be done in the `require-dev` so that the unit tests can work and so that other projects using the library are not required to use the same implementation